# Arguments documentation in caller and callee structure

Tags: documentation

Consider the following case:
a library contains a caller functions which calls multiple callee functions, and does nothing else.

```
def caller(a, b):
    callee1(a)
    callee2(b)

def calle1(a):
    ...

def calle2(b):
    ...
```

and the assumption is that the user might sometimes use the caller function
and sometimes use just one of the callee functions

I would like to document these functions.
As i see it the options to do this are the following:

**Option 1**
Document both the caller and the callees.
pros: The user will have a well-documented API whether he would like to use the caller function or the callee function
cons: The documentation of the parameters is duplicated, which can lead to mistakes and requires more maintenance.

**Option 2**
Document either the caller or the callees.
pros: No documentation duplication.
cons: The user will have not have a well-documented API in case he wishes to use the non-documented function

Both of these options, as i see them, have consequences i would like to avoid.

So my question is:
Are there any better ways to document this?
or are there better ways to structure this code to avoid these consequences?

Comment: Assuming this is Python and you're planning to use something like Sphinx, why not include *links* to the callee functions in the caller?

Comment: I wasn't aware of this capability of Sphinx! I went to read more and it seems like theres a lot i don't know about it :) 
So first of all thank you for introducing this to me.
And secondly, how would you suggest to formulate the caller docstring using these links?
Should i keep the method description and than write something similar to "for the arguments documentation look at <link to calle1> and <link to calle2>"?